# How did they realize vertical transition's animation in IPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, animation

There is an app with awesome vertical transition - [Haze](https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/haze/id594476963?mt=8). How did they realize this animation between home screen and settings? Did they use some framweork or something else? 
Thank you!

Comment: They wrote a goddamn big amount of CoreGraphics and CoreAnimation code.

Comment: That's not a transition, that's touch handling on (hopefully) a layer.  I would conjecture that the ripple effect is also another layer with a transform being applied.

Comment: @H2CO3 [OpenGL ES more than Core Graphics and Core Animation](http://www.imore.com/haze-brings-colorful-gesture-rich-weather-your-iphone).

Comment: @robmayoff OpenGL ES, which CoreGraphics and CoreAnimation uses too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Willi Wu, one of the app's creators, [tweeted this](https://twitter.com/williwu/status/302389140958347264):

> it’s OpenGL, CAShapeLayer and OpenAL as well.

Franz Bruckhoff, another of the creators, [tweeted this](https://twitter.com/_bartjacobs/status/302769898453626880) in response to the question “Is Haze primarily built with OpenGL?”

> Yep, mostly. Some CA too.

Answer (score 1):

- They are not seperate screens
- Use layers and drawing techniques
- They use core animation and core graphics
- Use touch event to detect gestures.
- Some mathemetical calculation
- some color sense ofcourse